WordPress Fails to Connect to MySQL with Custom User When Using localhost
I'm experiencing an issue with my local WordPress installation on Ubuntu 22.04. I have WordPress, MySQL, Apache2, and PHP installed and configured. I recently created a new MySQL user (youssef) and granted it privileges for my WordPress database. However, when I update the WordPress configuration file (wp-config.php) to use this new user and set the database host to localhost, I encounter a "Failed to establish a database connection" error.
The connection works fine when I change the database host to 127.0.0.1. Here’s a summary of the issue:

Current Setup:


MySQL Root User: Works with localhost and 127.0.0.1.
MySQL Custom User (youssef): Set up with host localhost.
WordPress Configuration (wp-config.php):

define('DB_NAME', 'your_database_name');
define('DB_USER', 'youssef');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'youssef');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');


Issue:


WordPress fails to connect to the database with the youssef user when DB_HOST is set to localhost.
The connection is successful when DB_HOST is set to 127.0.0.1.


Testing:


I can connect to MySQL using both localhost and 127.0.0.1 from the command line with the youssef user.
Other PHP and Laravel projects on the same server can connect to MySQL using both localhost and 127.0.0.1 with the youssef user.


Configuration Checks:


The MySQL user youssef has been granted appropriate privileges.
The MySQL server configuration (my.cnf) specifies the socket and bind-address settings.
Apache and PHP configurations are standard.


Question:
1-Why does WordPress fail to connect to the database when using localhost but succeed with 127.0.0.1 and with the root user using localhost?
2-What steps can I take to resolve this issue?


Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

which error with local host do you get?

On many systems, localhost is resolving to ::1, e.g. the IPV6 address for localhost. This is notably different than 127.0.0.1. However, please note [help/on-topic]: This question is not programming related, but about configuration issues, thus off-topic on stackoverflow.

MySQL / MariaDB usernames are a little strange. They look like 'youssef'@'%' or  'youssef'@'localhost'. Have you defined both of those? See this. https://serverfault.com/questions/544187/cant-connect-to-mysql-using-localhost-but-using-127-0-0-1-its-ok
